# Android force closing, what's the reason?

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, togglebutton, forceclose

I made the app.
when I press the togglebutton, then it is going to set alarm.
And then, when I press the togglebutoon 1 more time, then, it is going to cancel the alarm.
Plus, If I restart the app, it isn't changed that I was set before restarting the app.

but here is the problem, It works really well when I started it, but when I restarted it to cancel the alarm, then it is force closing.

so What should I do to make it no errors?

here is the code.

```
 @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("pref", 0);
    ToggleButton tglbutton = (ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.toggleButton1);
    TextView text1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.View1); 
    Boolean tgl = pref.getBoolean("toggleButton", false);
    String textData = pref.getString("text1", "");
    tglbutton.setChecked(tgl);
    text1.setText(textData);

}
   public void onToggleClicked(View view) {

        boolean on = ((ToggleButton) view).isChecked();
    if(on){


    alarm = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
    int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    {
        calendar0606.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.JUNE);
        calendar0606.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 6);
        int month0606 = calendar0606.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
        //month2= MARCH
        int day0606 = calendar0606.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        if(month > month0606){
            int year = calendar0606.get(Calendar.YEAR)+1;
            calendar0606.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);

        }
        else if(month <= month0606)
        {if(day >day0606){

            int year = calendar0606.get(Calendar.YEAR)+1;
            calendar0606.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);

        }}
                                                }
                     TextView text1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.View1); 

        text1.setText(R.string.working);}else{



            alarm.cancel(pendingIntent0606());

            return;

        }

        setAlarm0606();}

public void onStop(){
super.onStop();
SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("pref", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
ToggleButton tglbutton = (ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.toggleButton1);
TextView text1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.View1); 
editor.putBoolean("toggleButton", tglbutton.isChecked());
editor.putString("text1", text1.getText().toString());
editor.commit();
      }
```

---

logcat

---

```
03-01 22:37:59.207: D/szipinf(7912): Initializing inflate state
03-01 22:37:59.207: D/szipinf(7912): Initializing zlib to inflate
03-01 22:37:59.207: D/szipinf(7912): Initializing inflate state
03-01 22:37:59.207: D/szipinf(7912): Initializing zlib to inflate
03-01 22:37:59.207: D/szipinf(7912): Initializing inflate state
03-01 22:37:59.207: D/szipinf(7912): Initializing zlib to inflate
03-01 22:37:59.207: D/szipinf(7912): Initializing inflate state
03-01 22:37:59.207: D/szipinf(7912): Initializing zlib to inflate
03-01 22:37:59.207: D/szipinf(7912): Initializing inflate state
03-01 22:37:59.207: D/szipinf(7912): Initializing zlib to inflate
03-01 22:37:59.207: D/szipinf(7912): Initializing inflate state
03-01 22:37:59.207: D/szipinf(7912): Initializing zlib to inflate
03-01 22:37:59.207: D/szipinf(7912): Initializing inflate state
03-01 22:37:59.207: D/szipinf(7912): Initializing zlib to inflate
03-01 22:37:59.257: D/dalvikvm(7912): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 52K, 49% free 2783K/5379K, external 1973K/2108K, paused 31ms
03-01 22:39:23.089: D/dalvikvm(7912): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
03-01 22:41:02.128: I/dalvikvm(8188): Total arena pages for JIT: 11
03-01 22:41:12.167: D/AndroidRuntime(8188): Shutting down VM
03-01 22:41:12.167: W/dalvikvm(8188): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001e578)
03-01 22:41:12.210: E/AndroidRuntime(8188): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-01 22:41:12.210: E/AndroidRuntime(8188): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
03-01 22:41:12.210: E/AndroidRuntime(8188):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2154)
03-01 22:41:12.210: E/AndroidRuntime(8188):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2538)
03-01 22:41:12.210: E/AndroidRuntime(8188):     at android.widget.CompoundButton.performClick(CompoundButton.java:99)
03-01 22:41:12.210: E/AndroidRuntime(8188):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9152)
03-01 22:41:12.210: E/AndroidRuntime(8188):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
03-01 22:41:12.210: E/AndroidRuntime(8188):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-01 22:41:12.210: E/AndroidRuntime(8188):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
03-01 22:41:12.210: E/AndroidRuntime(8188):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
03-01 22:41:12.210: E/AndroidRuntime(8188):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-01 22:41:12.210: E/AndroidRuntime(8188):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
03-01 22:41:12.210: E/AndroidRuntime(8188):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:847)
03-01 22:41:12.210: E/AndroidRuntime(8188):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:605)
03-01 22:41:12.210: E/AndroidRuntime(8188):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-01 22:41:12.210: E/AndroidRuntime(8188): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
03-01 22:41:12.210: E/AndroidRuntime(8188):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-01 22:41:12.210: E/AndroidRuntime(8188):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
03-01 22:41:12.210: E/AndroidRuntime(8188):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2149)
03-01 22:41:12.210: E/AndroidRuntime(8188):     ... 12 more
03-01 22:41:12.210: E/AndroidRuntime(8188): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-01 22:41:12.210: E/AndroidRuntime(8188):     at com.simpson.knflagralarm.MainActivity.onToggleClicked(MainActivity.java:226)
03-01 22:41:12.210: E/AndroidRuntime(8188):     ... 15 more
```

Comment: Can you post the stacktrace? Using this stacktrace you can identify on what line it is failing. Make sure you have included this line in your question.

Comment: what's the stacktrace? Can u explain about that? then How can I use it?

Comment: When you are running the app you will see output in the logcat window. You can filter it by something unique to your app e.g part of the package name, so it onmly shows things you are interested. Id advise googling for logcat

Comment: the logcat says the part of canceling alarm is the problem.

Comment: But I couldn't know why that part is the problem..

Comment: Post the logcat output

Comment: I posted the logcat, please check it.

Answer (score 0):

Read the log it says:

> java.lang.NullPointerException at
>   com.simpson.knflagralarm.MainActivity.onToggleClicked(MainActivity.java:226)

This is your problem

Comment: Then, how can I fix this problem?

Comment: @user2899769 You did not show us the line numbers so I can't tell. Look at line 226 and try to understand what is null there, and then you be able to fix it.

Comment: 'alarm.cancel(pendingIntent0606());' is the code at line 226.

Comment: I guess that, since this only happens when the app is restarted, there is a variable not initialized the second time round that is accessed. Going to need to see your entire code.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, but I did EVERYTHING that I could do, I wasn't working. And the logcat's content is same as before..

Comment: If I send you the full code to you by email, then can you fix it or tell me the reason of this problem?

Comment: @user2899769 Show me line numbers